# How to show category together with "Next post" and "Previous post" WP [edited]

Tags: wordpress

My posts are tagged in the *City* category (which has the upper categories: *State* and *Country*).

```
- Country
-- State
--- City
```

I would like the level 2 (*State*) category to be shown along with respective post, replacing the words PREVIOUS and NEXT in the image with the corresponding category (*State*).

[image Previous/Next post link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoUxD.jpg)

NEW YORK - The previous post title

FLORIDA - The next post title

I want to make this adaptation in `twentyfourteen_post_nav()` from theme TwentyFourteen:

```
function twentyfourteen_post_nav() {
        $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
        $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

        if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <?php
            if ( is_attachment() ) :
                previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Published In</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                else :
                    previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Previous Post</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                    next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Next Post</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                endif;
                ?>
            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- .navigation -->
        <?php
    }
endif;
```